# viewmodel for gridview with column headers c#

Tags: c#, mvvm, datatable, data-annotations, observablecollection

I need a solution for this.

I need to create a view model for grid view. This viewmodel should be a strong typed one. ex.

```
List<Person> lstPersons=new List<Person>();
```

something like this. also, with this I should be able to have custom column header names. I can go with data annotation with enabling `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`
like,

```
class Person
{
      [DisplayName("Person Name")]
      public string name { get; set; }
}
```

something like this. But I have 2 issues with this.

1. I donno how to change this display name at run time.
2. Im using telerik RADGridView. with that when I'm using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` and `ShowColumnFooters="True"`, the whole UI get stucked. I think this s an error with telerik controls. So I have to define all columns in XAML and add binding path for each as well.

Anyway, This is possible with DataTable I think. but I feel data tables are very oldie struct and heavy object.

How to create a Viewmodel to achieve this? Any suggestions ?

Feel free to ask any question. im not sure above description is clear to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use the `DisplayName` attribute on your model, but as you pointed out, cannot change it at run-time. To do so, implement a dictionary in your ViewModel that populates

```
public PeopleGridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People;
    public Dictionary<string, string> PersonColumnHeaders;

    public PeopleGridViewModel()
    {
        // 1. write C# here to snag the property names from the typeof(Person)
        // 2. get the DisplayName attribute value for that property too.
        // 3. add the propertyName.ToString() and the DisplayName string to the dictionary as a key/value pair.

        // the result is you have a collection of column headers that start with the defaults from the propertys on the object... but they can be manipulated at run-time, and you don't havem them 100% hard typed like in adcool's example.
    }
}
```

I think the show column footers deal is a Telerik issue as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [discussion](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/binding-header-text.aspx) about data binding the column header.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the columns you want ot display is Fixed.... so your ViewModel Will be like

```
 class MyViewModel
 {
      //Implement Properties nad proper binding in Xaml and INotifyPropertyChanged for every property that you need on View Level
      ObservableCollection<Persons> persons;
      string columnheader1;
      string columnheader2;
      string columnheader3;

 }
```

## XAML

```
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns> 

            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn   DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Width="200">

                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header> 

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Columnheader1}"></TextBlock> 

                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header> 

                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn> 

            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{Binding Columnheader2}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsOnline}" MinWidth="200" Width="*"/> 

            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{Binding Columnheader3}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastActivityDate}" MinWidth="200"/> 

        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

This might do the trick..... :)